# Update multiple dependent inputs

Tags: shiny

I have a number of dependent input fields and would like to update all of them when the user clicks on a button. The use case is to load stored input settings. Below is a reproducible example. The choices for the "petal" selectInput depend on the selection in the "species" selectInput.

When I click on the button, only the first selectInput gets updated.

```
library(shiny)

data(iris)

# ui function
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("species.out"),
  uiOutput("petal.out"), 
  actionButton("update", label = "Update")
)

# server function
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$species.out = renderUI({
    selectInput("species", label = "", choices = sort(unique(iris$Species)))
  })

  output$petal.out = renderUI({

    req(input$species)

    selectInput("petal", label = "", choices = sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == input$species,]$Petal.Width)))
  })

  observeEvent(input$update,
               {
                 updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "species", selected = "virginica")
                 updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "petal", choices=sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == input$species,]$Petal.Width)), selected = "2.3")
               })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a way to update both fields at once?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to add another `observeEvent` for `input$species` where you would update the `selectInput` petal. Following is the modified code with the change:

```
library(shiny)

data(iris)

# ui function
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("species.out"),
  uiOutput("petal.out"), 
  actionButton("update", label = "Update")
)

# server function
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$species.out = renderUI({
    selectInput("species", label = "", choices = sort(unique(iris$Species)))
  })

  output$petal.out = renderUI({

    req(input$species)

    selectInput("petal", label = "", choices = sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == input$species,]$Petal.Width)))
  })

  observeEvent(input$update,
               {
                 updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "species", selected = "virginica")
                 # updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "petal", choices=sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == input$species,]$Petal.Width)), selected = "2.3")
               })


  observeEvent(input$species,{
    req(input$petal)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "petal", choices=sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == input$species,]$Petal.Width)), selected = "2.3")
  } )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

To update `input$petal` even when `input$species` is not the following code will work:

```
library(shiny)

data(iris)

# ui function
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("species.out"),
  uiOutput("petal.out"), 
  actionButton("update", label = "Update")
)

# server function
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$species.out = renderUI({
    selectInput("species", label = "", choices = sort(unique(iris$Species)))
  })

  output$petal.out = renderUI({

    req(input$species)

    selectInput("petal", label = "", choices = sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == input$species,]$Petal.Width)))
  })

  observeEvent(input$update,
               {
                 updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "species", selected = "virginica")
                 updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "petal", choices=sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == input$species,]$Petal.Width)), selected = "2.3")
               })


  observeEvent(input$species,{
    if(input$petal == "" || req(input$petal))
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "petal", choices=sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == input$species,]$Petal.Width)), selected = "2.3")
  } )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here I have changed the condition `req(input$petal)` to `if(input$petal == "" || req(input$petal))` and also added  `updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "petal", choices=sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == input$species,]$Petal.Width)), selected = "2.3")` in the `observeEvent` of `input$update`.

Comment: Thank you for the proposition. That solution doesn't work, if species is already selected to "virginica", but petal isn't "2.3". In this case the `observeEvent(input$species",..)` doesn't fire.

Comment: @WarrenBuffet have a look at the edited answer, it addresses your issue.

Comment: The updated code crashes , I receive the following error: `Warning: Error in ||: invalid 'y' type in 'x || y'` when I select a species. Also, if the code worked, wouldn't it try to load the stored value to `input$petal` each time the user changes species and not only when the user clicks on `Update`?

Comment: Oh ya I did not notice that. Then the easiest way would be to change `updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "petal", choices=sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == input$species,]$Petal.Width)), selected = "2.3")` to `updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "petal", choices=sort(unique(iris[iris$Species == "virginica",]$Petal.Width)), selected = "2.3")` in your original code.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work in general. :( If the selected species is not "virginica", then the petal selectInput isn't updated. This means the user has to click `Update` twice.

Comment: But based on your code when you click `update` the species will always be `virginica`. So how should that matter?

Comment: Think of the following scenario: a user changes some inputs but then decides to load stored settings. A click on `update` won't do, because if the currently selected species isn't `virginica`, another click is needed. In my real use case, there are 4 dependent input fields, so a user needs to click 4 times to load all stored settings.